# Chrome extension using sidebar

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been having a look at Chrome extensions and I'd like to create an extension that interacts with a web page using a sidebar. So, user clicks button to launch extension, and the current page splits, with the right hand portion displaying my extension. I tried below, but I see nothing (working or otherwise). I'm not overly surprised it's not working as I do not have a sidebar.html file for one thing. The reason I have that in the manifest is because I saw it in another post in this site. The suggestion there was to use the "sidebar" line in manifest.json, but "sidebar" isn't even mentioned in the documentation as being a valid part of the manifest syntax.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test 1",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test Extension 1",
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Testing",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
  "sidebar" : {},
  "permissions": [
    "experimental"
  ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<script>
  chrome.experimental.sidebar.show();
  chrome.experimental.sidebar.expand();
  chrome.experimental.sidebar.navigate({path: "sidebar.html"});
</script>
```

I've enabled 'experimental'.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So why don't you have `sidebar.html`?

Comment: Note that the sidebar API is going away in future versions of Chrome. These are the bleeding edge documents (note the `trunk` in the URL): http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that you are opening, theoretically, the sidebar inside your popup, not in the current page.

You should add a *content script* in the page, with a function that opens the sidebar. So, in your popup you should just retrieve the current tab then call this function from it.

Also, as Boris Smus said in your question, **sidebars will be discontinued in future versions**. So I advice you to create your own sidebar frame via *content scripts*.

---

### Update

To help you, I've made a simple extension that create a sidebar on current page.

@[Curtis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364485/curtis) hosted my sample extension on Github, you can clone it [here](https://github.com/curtislacy/inject-sidebar).

Comment: Thank you. Trying to create a sidebar frame with content script as you suggest but I can't find any coherent documentation, just snippets everywhere, nothing tying the pieces together. In manifest.json, I put `"content_scripts": ["js":["test_content_script.js"]}]`, so how does the script in there get invoked? Do I call a function in test_content_script from popup.html? Thanks.

Comment: The sidebar is for a specific url?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do that. I have downloaded it and it works beautifully. I will try to amend so that the sidebar does not hide part of the original page, but I am very grateful to you for getting me off the blocks! Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! If it solve your problem, please vote up the answer and mark it as accepted!

Comment: I marked it as accepted, but when I tried to vote up it told me I needed a reputation of at least 15.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a sidebar solution as well and ended up at
[Implement chrome.sidebar API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477424) thread.

According to [the Sidebar PRD](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18Tr8DPj9wh-BPZyfSa7ssFLuMJ3uGGhb9tDVwyIbNV4/edit), it is already possible to create sidebar by:

> 1. injecting a script into the page which edits the HTML of the page to display a sidebar by modifying the DOM to insert an iframe which
>      loads the contents of the sidebar from a remote server.
> 2. the injected script can edit the DOM directly to display a sidebar, the contents of which are passed via message.

However, there are many downsides (explained in the same document) with regard to:

> Usability, Performance, Security, Privacy (Extension sniffing as well as Third party cookies) and Accessibility.

You can [watch a demo](http://people.igalia.com/ltilve/screencast-perWindow.ogv) of what they are preparing for future Sidebar Component.

It might help in shipping the feature quicker if you star the thread.

### update

Per [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477424#c82), Chrome will not get a built-in sidebar component.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.