# Create always-present sidebar with Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I create an always-present sidebar in a Chrome browser extension?  Do I have to inject something into each page the user views?  That seems weird because it would disappear every time the user navigates to a new page.  Also, I'd be worried about my code and HTML interfering with the page and I can't possibly test every page on the net to be sure it works everywhere.

It looks like [there was an API for this that was just removed](http://codereview.chromium.org/9006027)?  Is this feature dead for good or are there any plans to bring it back?

Comment: +1 also interested in this feature. Please post an answer here if you see any new development :)

Comment: were u able to solve this. i would like to add a sidebar in gmail and looking on how it can be done

Comment: More activity on the same topic in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391320

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject HTML into every page. There was an experimental Sidebar API for a while but it was never developed to state that the Chromium team was happy with. They are still keeping the issue open but it is not currently being developed. You should [star the issue](http://crbug.com/51084) if you wish to get updates on it's progress.

**Update:**

The feature is removed and there is no further development on it.

Quoting from their [site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477424#c82):

> We will not be proceeding with this feature request. We recognize that there is a significant number of you who will be disappointed with this decision, evidenced in part by the many stars on this issue. We debated it extensively, both inside the team and with members of the community. In the end we decided that the WontFix resolution was more in keeping with Chrome's core value of simplicity.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for linking me to the issue

Answer (score 1):

Almost a decade later, Extension Manifest V3 now provides the [`chrome.sidePanel`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/) API. It provides a persistent pane that can be used to host an extension page, completely separate from the main page.

You can find examples for this API [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/#examples), or on GitHub at [`chrome-extensions-samples/functional-examples`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples).

---

In short, to create a sidepanel, add the permission to your manifest:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "sidePanel"
  ],
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "sidepanel.html"
  }
}
```

Then, add sidepanel contents:

```html
<!-- sidebar.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Sidepanel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Some sidebar HTML
  </body>
</html>
```

You should then be able to open the sidebar using "Show side panel" in the browser navigation and clicking the extension name.