# Is it advisable to develop Chrome sidebar extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

We want to develop a chrome sidebar extension, and I got to know that sidebar support will not be available in the chrome future versions.[Please refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391320/chrome-extension-using-sidebar/7395084#7395084).

So is it advisable to develop sidebar extension?

Comment: _More information about this will be helpful_ - I couldn't have said better myself; it's unclear what you even mean.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this API is [not even listed as experimental](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental) in the current documentation.

It may be already removed, might change at any time, and has no timeline for becoming released.

The reply that says it's going away is from a Google Engineer, so it's highly probable that it  will never reach Stable.

Therefore, *it makes no sense to try and develop for that*.

Comment: Thanks Xan, Our extension is not going to be simple button click event. It will contain considerable UI elements and corresponding actions. So what could be the better way to develop this extension other than sidebar?